# Strange face appearance

Tags: edit-mode, topology

The below shading has me scratching my head.

The faces are coplanar, as far as I can tell.  It's not a normal issue.  The faces are attached (I can drag them around and everything stays attached.)  Also, I confirmed there is only one face present.

If I delete the faces and recreate them, the shading is corrected.

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Oh, I tried turning on Auto-smoothing, and that fixes it.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: I think individual faces can have shade smooth or shade flat active.

Comment: Your normals may be the wrong way around. Try recalculating normals.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen with “custom split normal data” on the geometry. Go to the Properties tab and clear the custom split normals data. That should fix it.

This is technically a duplicate question.